# Error “Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)” mean?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var isPrime = true

if Int(numberGuessed.text!)! > 5 {
    isPrime = true
} else {
    isPrime = false
}

if isPrime {
    resultLabel.text! = "\(numberGuessed.text) is prime!"
} else {
    resultLabel.text! = "\(numberGuessed.text) is not prime!"
}
```

Ignore the isPrime as I'm not really testing whether or not something is really prime. Why does it give me this error? There's no mistake in the code

Comment: Post your error. Your code is working on my side.

Comment: Get rid of your exclamation marks in your code and make sure your numberGuessed it is properly connected to the outlet and that there is no old outlet connection that you forgot to delete properly